# PHP Delete not working as I would I like

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

Can someone help me. My delete code below works, but it's deleting the most recent Favorited file and not the specific file chosen. Here's the code:

```
while($row=$query->fetch())
{

$id=$row['id'];
$vid=$row['thread_id'];
$preview=$row['preview'];
$tt=$row['thread_title'];
$fav=$row['fav'];

$List.='<form action="" method="POST" id="postForm">
<div class="LISTT"><a href="VP2.php?id='.$vid.'">'.$preview.'</a><br/><label     id="pwords">'.$tt.'</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" id="DeleteButton"/>
</div></form>'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$query=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM favorite WHERE thread_id=:thread");
$query->execute(array(':thread'=>$vid));
}

}
```

Comment: you're spitting out a bunch of rows of data, but never check WHICH of those many rows' submit buttons was clicked.

Comment: How do I check? I've been trying to figure this out for the pass 2 days.

Comment: your code makes little sense. spit out a bunch of database results, **IF** a submit was done, then delete the db record of the row you just spit out, leaving an invalid ID in your form.

Comment: This comes down to one underlying fact. If your query is deleting the most recent item, it is because `$vid` IS the ID of the most recent item. Have you output the variable to confirm it is the correct value?

Comment: So how do I assign a unique id to each submit form?

Comment: I'm willing to change my entire code if u guys show me the right path.

Comment: @NidMoass - a couple of things, then. You only need one form tag, for the whole page, so you can put that outside your loop. Each row you print from the database needs to pass a unique ID number - the row's primary key will work; you can do this by adding an input button for each row and giving them a unique name. Once the form has been submitted, look and see which button was pressed, and delete the appropriate row - you can put the logic for that before the existing code, so deleted rows aren't shown in the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a hidden form field that contains the Thread ID into your form, then read that back in your form handler, something like this:

```
while($row=$query->fetch())
{
$id=$row['id'];
$vid=$row['thread_id'];
$preview=$row['preview'];
$tt=$row['thread_title'];
$fav=$row['fav'];

$List.='<form action="" method="POST" id="postForm">
<div class="LISTT"><a href="VP2.php?id='.$vid.'">'.$preview.'</a><br/><label id="pwords">'.$tt.'</label><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="thread" value="' . $vid . '" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" id="DeleteButton"/>
</div></form>'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$id = $_POST["thread"];
$query=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM favorite WHERE thread_id=:thread");
$query->execute(array(':thread'=>$id));
}
}
```

Comment: One more thing I forgot - you might want to put the form handler on the top, since if you do this, your page will still display the deleted record until it is refreshed

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you have the If statement in your while loop. The logic in the code you have given is to delete records when $_POST['submit'] is set. So it will follow the loop to delete the records and not a specific record.

You need to pass the id you want to delete to the user, as you are using form to do this, have a hidden field with the id.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM favorite WHERE thread_id=:thread");
    $query->execute(array(':thread'=>$_POST['id']));
}

while($row=$query->fetch())
{

    $id=$row['id'];
    $vid=$row['thread_id'];
    $preview=$row['preview'];
    $tt=$row['thread_title'];
    $fav=$row['fav'];

    $List.='<form action="" method="POST" id="postForm">
<div class="LISTT"><a href="VP2.php?id='.$vid.'">'.$preview.'</a><br/><label     id="pwords">'.$tt.'</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" id="DeleteButton"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="'.$id.'" />
</div></form>'; 

}
```